# Hoare Partition Algorithm Index out of a bounds

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

[image: some page 178 depicting an ALGORITHM HoarePartition]

```
while array[i] <= pivot:
    i += 1
    # print("I")
    if i == len(array):
        i -= 1
        break
```

This is what I am using to prevent the out of a bounds problem, but I think I am not implementing the idea of a "sentinel" as it appears in the text and my algorithm is running much slower than I anticipated.

What does the book mean when it says append a "sentinel" to the array A[0..n-1]?

Comment: A sentinel is an actual data value that you add to the array, such that it has a constant value that you can recognize as having a specific meaning, and not being part of the actual data (preferably a named constant). I would say MAXINT, but that doesn't really work in python :)

Comment: Please add [where above page 178 comes from](/help/referencing).

Comment: @greybeard - it's from a textbook and doing a web search, I find a few matches for Hoare partition page 178, but none of them mentions the name of the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Append `p + 1`, for instance, as it will clearly stop the growth of `i`. Or, definitely better, the maximum value of the particular numeric type array elements belong to. Any value that allows to break the loop while still guarding the array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm in the question refers to an old version of Hoare partition scheme, which changed over time. By changing the inner loops to break on elements equal to pivot (left scan loops on < instead of <=, right scan loops on > instead of >=), the need for sentinel elements or bounds checking was eliminated.

Look at the history and Hoare partition scheme sections in the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort